# Prepare for segue: the sender is the Table View and not the Table View Cell

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to implement Peek & Pop functionality with 3D touch. I'm following the guidance on the [Apple Website](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/peek_and_pop/implementing_peek_and_pop).

It says that I should get the index path of the currently selected cell in my prepare for segue method the following way:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let selectedTableViewCell = sender as? UITableViewCell,
         let indexPath = tableView.indexPath(for: selectedTableViewCell)
         else { preconditionFailure("Expected sender to be a valid table view cell") }
```

However when I call this, I get the precondition error. I checked the value of sender, and indeed, it is not a table view cell but my Table View Controller.

When I get the index path this way:

```
guard let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow else {fatalError()}
```

It works when I simply select the table view cell. It does not work when I try to peek. It shows me the peeked table view, but it is empty. I was expecting this because the Apple documentation does mention that `indexPathForSelectedRow` returns nil when peeking.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong with the first method and why the sender is the Table View Controller and not the Table View Cell. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unclear why this error occurs after changing your code as @vadian suggested.

That was my only idea too. We should see the rest of your code, I think it must be a problem somewhere in there. Without that I think nobody can say much else.

However, I think there is something you might do (though this is not a solution to your original problem):
If you're following the Apple tutorial like you said, you already set the index path in your `previewingContext(_:viewControllerForLocation:)` method. If that works, you might be able to manipulate the data you want there. And when you segue to the other VC you can use `indexPathForSelectedRow` which as you mentioned works when you select but not when you peek.
Without seeing the rest of the code, that's the best I can do.

Comment: Thanks man, this solved it, it works. Brilliant. As for the original error, it unclear to me too..

Answer (score 0):

To get this code to work you have to connect the segue by <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-dragging from the *table view cell* rather than from the *view controller*.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed it, but still getting the same error unfortunately.

Comment: If the connection starts at the cell (if you select the segue the cell is highlighted) the error must not occur.